# How to change brightness mode from inside the app and from the system

Tags: flutter, sharedpreferences, android-theme

I am trying to allow the user to change brightness mode from light to dark and vice versa through a bitton in the settings. I am using `shared preferences` package to save this value locally.
what I need is that at the first time launching the app, there won't be that `brightnessMode` boolean, so I take the brightness of the system. The problem is that when I am using `Theme()`, I need to change its brightness to the one the user chooses, so how can I change the brightness of the theme according to what the user chose and also if it is the first time, it chooses the brightness of the system.

Here I am setting the value of the boolean to the loaded data, but if it's null, I check if the system is in dark mode or not and return it.

```
loadData() async {
  LocalVars.darkMode = await LocalVars.loadVariable('darkMode', bool) ??
      Brightness.dark ==
          SchedulerBinding.instance.platformDispatcher.platformBrightness;
}
```

I tried to check for `darkMode` boolean and set the brightness of the theme according to it.

```
theme: ThemeData(
              brightness:
                  LocalVars.darkMode ? Brightness.dark : Brightness.light,
....
```

but it returns `LateInitializationError`, what is causing this problem and if someone knows a better way to achieve what I need, please tell me.

Thanks in advance.

**Edit**

In summary, I need to change the theme of the app with a button